Magnifying Glass Effect - part 2
After I got this sample working, thanks to help from a few people, I wondered about doing it in a way that allows it to be responsive and to also include any filters added to the source image. I came up with this:


// The magnification factor; an integer greater than 1
const zoom = 3; 
// The radius of the glass (as a percentage of the image's width)
// a number between 1 and 100, inclusive
const radius = 25;

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const glass = document.querySelector('.glass');
const { style } = glass;
style.setProperty('--zoom', zoom);

// Add the magnified image as a clone
// This way it'll include any filter applied to the original image
const img = container.querySelector('img').cloneNode();
glass.append(img);

container.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  // ISSUE: The diameter of the glass is, as the magnification gets bigger, smaller than expected
  const clipPath = `${radius / zoom}% at ${e.offsetX * zoom}px ${e.offsetY * zoom}px`;
  
  style.setProperty('--clip-path', clipPath);
  style.setProperty('--left', `${(zoom - 1 ) * -e.offsetX}px`)
  style.setProperty('--top', `${(zoom - 1 ) * -e.offsetY}px`)
});
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: fit-content;
  left: 8%;
  top: 20%;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: none;

  &> img {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
    display: block;
  }

  &:hover .glass {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .glass {
    position: absolute;
    left: var(--left);
    top:  var(--top);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    clip-path: circle(var(--clip-path));
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    opacity: 0;

    img {
      width: calc(var(--zoom) * 100%);
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/Z4aOFrum.jpg" alt="bg">
  <div class="glass"></div>
</div>



The issue that I can't work out how it's happening (and so I can't fix) is that when the zoom factor is 2 the displayed radius of the glass matches the value I set - for example, if I set the radius to 25 the glass displays at 50% of the source image - but if I increase the zoom the glass displays smaller than expected even though the magnified image is larger (and so the glass size should match.)

At a zoom factor of 1 the radius of 25% would be 25 / 1 which is 25. At zoom of 2 the zoomed image is twice the size so I expected the radius to be equal to 25 / 2 which is 12.5 (which seems is what it displays at.) Then why does it not follow that when zoom equals, say, 10 that radius is equal to 25 / 10 which is 2.5 as the image is 10 times larger?

Thanks for the reply and the link. I can see now that I don't quite understand how percentages are applied with clip-path:circle(). Because I need it responsive and I don't want to continually be checking/setting a pixel size I'll look into do a magnifying lens some other way.
